# Making aligned the symbol "≤" and "≥" on invisible from top to the bottom in Overleaf LaTeX

Tags: tables, formatting, errors, vertical-alignment, mathematics

How do you make the invisible table "≤" and "≥" aligned from top to bottom as shown in the following image on LaTeX Overleaf?
This is the code that I made

```latex
\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{>{$}c<{$}>{$}c<{$}>{$}c<{$}}
$A(\triangle ADB)$ & $\leq A(\text{sector } ADB)$ & $\leq A(\triangle ADF)$ \\
$\dfrac{ab\sin(c)}{2}$ & $\leq \dfrac{r^2\theta}{2}$ & $\leq \dfrac{ab\sin(c)}{2}$ \\
$\dfrac{(1)(1)\sin(x)}{2}$ & $\leq \dfrac{(1^2)x}{2}$ & $\leq \dfrac{(1)\tan(x)\sin 90^{\circ}}{2}$ \\
$\dfrac{\sin(\theta)}{2}$ & $\leq \dfrac{x}{2}$ & $\leq \dfrac{\tan(x)}{2}$ \\
$2 \cdot \dfrac{\sin(x)}{2}$ & $\leq 2 \cdot \dfrac{x}{2}$ & $\leq 2 \cdot \dfrac{\tan(x)}{2}$ \\
$\sin(x)$ & $\leq x$ & $\leq \tan(x)$ \\
$\sin(x)$ & $\leq x$ & $\leq \dfrac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}$ \\
$\dfrac{1}{\sin(x)}$ & $\geq \dfrac{1}{x}$ & $\geq \dfrac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}$ \\
$\sin(x) \cdot \dfrac{1}{\sin(x)}$ & $\geq \sin(x) \cdot \dfrac{1}{x}$ & $\geq \sin(x) \cdot \dfrac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}$ \\
$1$ & $\geq \dfrac{\sin(x)}{x}$ & $\geq \cos(x)$
\end{tabular}
```

And this is what it looks like:

[image: The screenshot results on Overleaf PDF]

How to make this look right on the *Figure 1* turns to this?

[image: The screenshot results on Microsoft Word]

Comment: use the align environment from amsmath, see amsldoc.pdf for the documentation.

Comment: Because of math mode mistakes, your code does not compile without errors, if I add it into the body of a minimum document using class `article` and packages `amsmath` and `array`. Please always show a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964) that does not show errors, which are not part of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple suggest would be to put the relations in their own columns:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{*5c}
A(\triangle ADB) & \leq & A(\text{sector } ADB) & \leq & A(\triangle ADF) \\
\dfrac{ab\sin(c)}{2} & \leq & \dfrac{r^2\theta}{2} & \leq & \dfrac{ab\sin(c)}{2} \\
\dfrac{(1)(1)\sin(x)}{2} & \leq & \dfrac{(1^2)x}{2} & \leq & \dfrac{(1)\tan(x)\sin 90^{\circ}}{2} \\
\dfrac{\sin(\theta)}{2} & \leq & \dfrac{x}{2} & \leq & \dfrac{\tan(x)}{2} \\
2 \cdot \dfrac{\sin(x)}{2} & \leq & 2 \cdot \dfrac{x}{2} & \leq & 2 \cdot \dfrac{\tan(x)}{2} \\
\sin(x) & \leq & x & \leq & \tan(x) \\
\sin(x) & \leq & x & \leq & \dfrac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)} \\
\dfrac{1}{\sin(x)} & \geq & \dfrac{1}{x} & \geq & \dfrac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)} \\
\sin(x) \cdot \dfrac{1}{\sin(x)} & \geq & \sin(x) \cdot \dfrac{1}{x} & \geq & \sin(x) \cdot \dfrac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)} \\
1 & \geq & \dfrac{\sin(x)}{x} & \geq & \cos(x)
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

This would also work inside a `table` environment if needed.

I also reduced your inflationary use of switching to math mode by simply using an `array` environment within a formula environment. This not only eliminates various errors, it also makes the code much clearer in my opinion.

Comment: For you, I also thank you for the code because your code compiles perfectly with Overleaf

Answer (score 1):

Use five columns.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\setlength\arraycolsep{2pt}
\setlength\defaultaddspace{8pt}

$\begin{array}{ ccccc }
A(\triangle ADB) & \leq & A(\text{sector } ADB) & \leq & A(\triangle ADF) \\
\addlinespace
\dfrac{ab\sin(x)}{2} & \leq & \dfrac{r^2x}{2} & \leq & \dfrac{ab\sin(c)}{2} \\
\addlinespace
\dfrac{(1)(1)\sin(x)}{2} & \leq & \dfrac{(1^2)x}{2} & \leq & \dfrac{(1)\tan(x)\sin 90^{\circ}}{2} \\
\addlinespace
\dfrac{\sin(x)}{2} & \leq & \dfrac{x}{2} & \leq & \dfrac{\tan(x)}{2} \\
\addlinespace
2 \cdot \dfrac{\sin(x)}{2} & \leq & 2 \cdot \dfrac{x}{2} & \leq & 2 \cdot \dfrac{\tan(x)}{2} \\
\addlinespace
\sin(x) & \leq & x & \leq & \tan(x) \\
\addlinespace
\sin(x) & \leq & x & \leq & \dfrac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)} \\
\addlinespace
\dfrac{1}{\sin(x)} & \geq & \dfrac{1}{x} & \geq & \dfrac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)} \\
\addlinespace
\sin(x) \cdot \dfrac{1}{\sin(x)} & \geq & \sin(x) \cdot \dfrac{1}{x} & \geq & \sin(x) \cdot \dfrac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)} \\
\addlinespace
1 & \geq & \dfrac{\sin(x)}{x} & \geq & \cos(x)
\end{array}$

\caption{Long derivation of a very important fact}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Adapt the values of `\arraycolsep` and `\defaultaddspace` to suit your taste.

I fixed a couple of errors: the first “c” in the second row should be “x”; in two instances, “” should be “x”. Never have a table without its caption.

[image]

Comment: @Mico I don’t think so

Comment: For the $$\theta$$ I actually left it there because that is the sector area formula in radians $$A=\dfrac{r^2\theta}{2}$$. But once again I thank you for the correction and also the help. Because the code you provided works and can be compiled by Overleaf.